# Error while using the weights option in nlme in r

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

Hi i am trying to fit a power curve to model some observations in an nlme.
However, I know some observations to be less reliable than others (reliability of each OBSID reflected in the WEIV in the dummy data), relatively independent of variance, and I quantified this beforehand and wish to include it as weights in my model. Moreover, I know a part of my variance is correlated with my independent variable so I cannot use directly the variance as weights.

This is my model:

```
coeffs_start = lm(log(DEPV)~log(INDV), filter(testdummy10,DEPV!=0))$coefficients

nlme_fit <- nlme(DEPV ~ a*INDV^b, 
                      data = testdummy10,
                      fixed=a+b~ 1, 
                      random = a~ 1, 
                      groups = ~ PARTID, 
                      start = c(a=exp(coeffs_start[1]), b=coeffs_start[2]),
                      verbose = F,
                      method="REML",
                      weights=varFixed(~WEIV))
```

This is some sample dummy data (I know it is not a great fit but it's fake data anyway) : https://github.com/FlorianLeprevost/dummydata/blob/main/testdummy10.csv

This runs well without the "weights" argument, but when I add it I get this error and I am not sure why because I believe it is the correct syntax:

```
Error in recalc.varFunc(object[[i]], conLin) : 
dims [product 52] do not match the length of object [220]
In addition: Warning message:
In conLin$Xy * varWeights(object) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I maybe found a response to my problem in the GLMMadaptive package manual: a numeric vector of weights. These are simple multipliers on the log-likelihood
contributions of each group/cluster, i.e., we presume that there are multiple replicates of each group/cluster denoted by the weights. The length of ‘weights‘ need
to be equal to the number of independent groups/clusters in the data.

Comment: This is an nlme but that's gone unfixed since at least 2004. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235304/error-while-using-the-weights-option-in-nlme-in-r.